# Send string data from Java/Erlang to Ada

Tags: java, sockets, erlang, ipc, ada

I would like to create some interface in Java or Erlang, that process user commads, create string and send this string to Ada application. How I can do that in proper way?
I tried do this with sockets but it doesn't work?
It will be grateful, if you could provide me some sample code or some references.

Here is Ada task Server code:

```
task body ConfigServer is
   Receiver   : GNAT.Sockets.Socket_Type;
   Connection : GNAT.Sockets.Socket_Type;
   Client     : GNAT.Sockets.Sock_Addr_Type;
   Channel    : GNAT.Sockets.Stream_Access;
   S : Unbounded_String;
   C : Character;
  begin
     Put_Line("SERVER CONFIG STARTED...");
     GNAT.Sockets.Create_Socket (Socket => Receiver);
     GNAT.Sockets.Set_Socket_Option
       (Socket => Receiver,
        Option => (Name    => GNAT.Sockets.Reuse_Address, Enabled => True));
     GNAT.Sockets.Bind_Socket
       (Socket  => Receiver,
        Address => (Family => GNAT.Sockets.Family_Inet,
                    Addr   => Addresses (Get_Host_By_Name (Host_Name), 1),
                    Port   => 2080));
     GNAT.Sockets.Listen_Socket (Socket => Receiver);
     loop
        GNAT.Sockets.Accept_Socket
          (Server  => Receiver,
           Socket  => Connection,
           Address => Client);
        Ada.Text_IO.Put_Line
          ("Client connected from " & GNAT.Sockets.Image (Client));
        Channel := GNAT.Sockets.Stream (Connection);
        begin
           loop
              C := Character'Input (Channel); 
              if C /= '.' then
                Append(S, C);
              else
                Put_Line("Received: " & S);
                Set_Unbounded_String(S, "");
              end if;
           end loop;
        exception
           when Ada.IO_Exceptions.End_Error =>
              null;
        end;
        GNAT.Sockets.Close_Socket (Connection);
     end loop;
  end ConfigServer;
```

Erlang code:

```
-module (client).
-compile([export_all]).

sendMsg() ->
    {ok, Socket} = gen_udp:open(2560),
    gen_udp:send(Socket, {127,0,0,1}, 2080, "Hello"),
    gen_udp:close(Socket).
```

Java code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
             socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 2080);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

       PrintStream output = null;

       try {
           output = new PrintStream(socket.getOutputStream());
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       String input;
       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       do {
           input = scanner.nextLine();
           output.print(input);
       }while (input.equalsIgnoreCase("EXIT"));


        try {
           output.close();
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I think that's problem is that Java and Erlang working in virtual environemnt and I need some low level API to sockets. Am I right?

Comment: Post the code you've tried.

Comment: The Erlang code appears to be using UDP, but the Ada code is using TCP. The Java code only outputs one line before exiting (but that line should get sent). **And**, “it doesn’t work” doesn’t help us. In what way doesn’t it work?

Comment: Yes, you're right. When I created TCP connection in Erlang and corrected Ada code to use "localhost" like mentioned below it works too. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m on OS X, and I got this to start working by

(Ada)

```
GNAT.Sockets.Bind_Socket
  (Socket  => Receiver,
   Address => (Family => GNAT.Sockets.Family_Inet,
               Addr   => Addresses (Get_Host_By_Name (“localhost"), 1),
               Port   => 2080));
```

It turns out that, on OS X, `Host_Name` returns `nidhoggr.local` (my machines are named after dragon-like entities, and I was running short), which has one network address, `192.168.1.74`. `”localhost”`, on the other hand, does give you `127.0.0.1`.

(Java)

```
do {
    input = scanner.nextLine();
    output.print(input);
}while (!input.equalsIgnoreCase("EXIT"));
```

(see the `!`)

Comment: I'm grateful for your help! It doesn't work because of Host_Name and wrong address like you wrote.